# How to set the “Version” in the Control Panel's “Add or Remove Programs” using jnlp file

Tags: java, windows, jnlp

I am installing an application using JNLP.

Its entry is added under Add/Remove Programs but other useful information is not shown.

In Windows XP it only shows entries corresponding to vendor and description subtags of the information tag.

Is there any way to add version and size information about the application from the jnlp file?